# Hive out of memory even with two rows

Tags: hadoop, hive, out-of-memory

I tested Hive with the following queries:

```
create table test (key string, value string) stored as orc;
insert into table test values ('a','a'), ('b','b');
select key, count(*) from test group by key;
```

And I got the out-of-memory error:

> Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:157)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:137)

I have searched online, but people usually got this error when they were working on some bigger files. In my case, the file only has two rows, and my computer has 14G memory.

I have set /etc/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh HADOOP_HEAPSIZE to 1024. It does not work.

Comment: Have you checked the heap space for Tez? You can find some recommendations here: http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1.10/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap1-11.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I increased tez.runtime.io.sort.mb, but I got this error instead: tez.runtime.io.sort.mb should be larger than 0 and should be less than the available task memory

Then I increased hive.tez.java.opts (and some other parameters) as suggested by @Hellmar Becker. That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while creating the truck table as ORC in this [Hadoop Hello World tutorial](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/hello-world-an-introduction-to-hadoop-hcatalog-hive-and-pig/). You can try to compress the ORC storage using:

```
CREATE TABLE XXX STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES ("orc.compress.size"="1024");
```

I hope this helps (for me, it worked).

Answer (score 0):

They also agree that its issue in the Sandbox...
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/34426/failure-to-execute-hive-query-from-lab-2.html#comment-35900

Answer (score -1):

Tried many solutions , not working . Time being using this work around -

```
CREATE TABLE avg_mileage (truckid STRING,avgmpg BIGINT ) STORED AS ORC;
```